# Deleting LDAP record with 0x0A in CN (Java)

Tags: java, ldap, cnf, lds

I'm trying to delete ADLDS user records created by Microsoft's conflict resolution model.
Microsoft describes the creation of the new records as

```
The new RDN will be <Old RDN>\0ACNF:<objectGUID>
```

These are the records I'm trying to delete from my environment.

My search for uid=baduser will return two CNs:

> cn=John R. Doe 123456

and

> cn=John R. Doe 123456 
>  CNF:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000

The second record has the \0A in the cn.

Executing a ctx.destroySubcontext(cn) on it errors out like this:

> cn=John R. Doe 123456
> CNF:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000,c=US: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-0310022D, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8349

What am I missing to be able to delete a record with a cn that contains a line feed character?

note: I also can't seem to read/modify this \0A record using JXplorer. Clicking on the record after a search results in the same BAD_NAME error.

Answer (score 0):

```
String commonName = attr.get("cn").get().toString().replace("\n", "\\\\0A");
```

A simple replacement of the \n character worked for me.